# Is it safe to destroy null

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a component that creates several `GameObject`'s and I would like to destroy those objects when the component is destroyed. The game object is not created in `Start` so it would be possible that it is `null` when `OnDestroy` is called for the component. So is it safe to do `Destroy(null)` in Unity? or should I check for `null` before trying to destroy an object?

Comment: This should be super easy to test, why don't you try it yourself? Create a coroutine, destroy the GameObject, wait a second and try to destroy it again and see what happens.

Comment: No, it is not. You would get an error, not an exception so you can't even catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel answered, this is an easy thing to try, so try it yourself, but let's say you won't be able to tell if the component is null or notو You can use try

like that

```
try{
   Destroy(Some.gameObject);
}
catch{}
```

Although it is not known whether the component is empty or not It is almost impossible

Comment: Afaik Unity logs an error but doesn't throw an exception ?might be wrong though) in which case you can't even catch it .. you should rather make the check properly

Comment: Yes, you are right, as I said above